# Ruby on Rails Search Same Page

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, search, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Total Rails Beginner here, but my first app is very close to finished. I am working on an application for a casino in order for them to process background checks. There is an Investigation model and an Applicant model. I am using the applicant_id as the foreign key in my Investigation Model.

What I would like for the Investigation form to be able to do is to search applicants by name, and then display information automatically such as dob: social: etc... All on the same page. However, when I do the search for applicant it "submits" the investigation form.

I have been reading all day about AJAX and remote: :true hash. I just don't quite understand what I am doing wrong. Whenever I click  "search" I am redirected to the investigation_show_path. I am sorry if this is a silly or repeat question, but I just can't render a solution to this problem.

My new investigation view has this search bar in it

```
<section>
  <%= form_tag applicants_path, :method => 'get', :id => "applicants_search", remote: :true do %>
    <p><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
       <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></p>
       <div id="applicant"><%= render 'applicant' %></div>
       <% end %> <br>
</section>
```

I have a partial that just has <%= @applicants %> in it. I included the following in a new.js file in the investigations view folder.

```
$("#applicants").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("applicants")) %>");
```

I also included in my application.js file

```
$(function() {
 $("#applicants th a, #applicants").live("click", function() {
  $.getScript(this.href);
  return false;
   });
  $("#applicants_search input").keyup(function() {
$.get($("#applicants_search").attr("action"),      $("#applicants_search").serialize(), null, "script");
return false;
});
});
});
```

In my applicants controller I have

```
  def index
    @applicants = Applicant.search(params[:search])
  end
```

All this and I am still taken to the "show Investigation" page, when all I want is a list of applicants to show up on my page. I am very tired and know I am probably missing something so obvious, or I am just lacking the knowledge of the fundamental concepts. I have watched the Rails Cast video and tried following other tutorials online, but am always redirected to a different page.  This is my very first time ever trying anything AJAXy in one of my apps. Any help is greatly appreciated as refactoring this model was my last task before I call this app done (for now of course).

Happy Coding!

```
    Started POST "/investigations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-28 14:37:31 -0400
Processing by InvestigationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"D1/oNHobbBIBtven3CWRkR8id5eZdzoZgJzD68N73epH5XyoPTKr3y2fi2Yl/IE9aEVqxK0V6ujRPx6WtTwvKg==", "search"=>"jared"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "investigations" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-04-28 18:37:31.073638"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-28 18:37:31.073638"]]
   (215.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/investigations/15
Completed 302 Found in 222ms (ActiveRecord: 215.6ms)

Started GET "/investigations/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-28 14:37:31 -0400
Processing by InvestigationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Investigation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "investigations".* FROM "investigations" WHERE "investigations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
  Rendered investigations/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 332ms (Views: 328.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: We need to see the `applicants_search` action code and its associated view. Since the form is pointed at this action then that code (and whether it redirects or just renders a response) is going to be where the issue is. The model code has nothing to do with this so you can take it out of your question. Also, the `InvestigationsController` has nothing to do with this, unless your routes map the `applicants_search` action into an action on that controller. But the `InvestigationsController#new` action definitely isn't related because **that's not what does the searching.**

Comment: hey jeff thanks for the reply I often just include model view and controller code for my rails questions just out of practice, but I took those out

Comment: Understood, but I still don't see the code for the `applicants_search` action. Where's the controller code that this form tag triggers:

`<%= form_tag applicants_path, :method => 'get', :id => "applicants_search", remote: :true do %>`

Comment: That is because i am doing this totally wrong and following along in tutorials

Comment: I dont have that and I think that is my problem

Comment: Where would i write something like that and what would it look like I am sorry total beginner questions

Comment: It must be triggering something, because you get the redirect. Look at your log and see which action is being triggered when you submit the search form, then post the code for that action.

Comment: I am looking at the /log/development file, put I am not seeing anything useful is that the right place to be lookinjg?

Comment: All the code aside I guess my question is, you are creating a new background check on your New Investigation Page. You want to allow the user the ability to search for applicants from the Applicant table. You want that information to show up on the same page. How does one do this, if there is a quick answer

Comment: yes, if you're in development working on this, when you submit that form a log entry should show up

Comment: And to answer your other question, basically you reply with JS that replaces elements on the page, but I think you have that code already. I think the problem is linking the AJAX search to the action and the view, which is why I'm going that direction. My point is you haven't posted the code that I need to see to actually know where the problem is, so I'm trying to solve that issue first.

Comment: I really feel so foolish, but when you say applicant_search action are you referring to a route? Code in my applicants controller? applicants model maybe? I am so confused and have been up for days trying to meet my deadline.